# Pandas: Compress two close timestamped rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
       id               timestamp  value1               value2
0         A 2000-01-01 0:00:49.345            0  14319414583119773928
1         A 2000-01-01 0:00:49.353            3                     0
2         A 2000-01-01 0:00:50.346            0  14319414565939874728
3         A 2000-01-01 0:00:50.354            3                     0
...
```

- Format is in a pandas data frame.
- I'd like to compress the rows using the timestamp fields when less than Xsec and use the max value1 and value2.

E.g.

```
        id               timestamp  value1               value2
0         A 2000-01-01 0:00:49.349            3  14319414583119773928
1         A 2000-01-01 0:00:50.350            3  14319414565939874728
```

I've tried to group by, but this creates some empty buckets which is undesirable. These timestamp values are so close, I'd just like to be able to treat them as the same thing. Can join on either timestamp or use the mid point between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Grouper`

```
df.value2=df.value2.astype(str)# why I change to str , cause the int is too big , when calculated panda push it to negative  
df.groupby([df.id,pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1s')]).max()
Out[326]: 
                       id  value1                value2
id timestamp                                           
A  2000-01-01 00:00:49  A       3  14319414583119773928
   2000-01-01 00:00:50  A       3  14319414565939874728
```